# How to calculate for each line in Crytal Report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am creating a Crystal report where I have to show the calculation of three columns and show it to another column. Which is something Like this:

```
 Gross   Total   Insurance   Net (this should be the formula field)
   1       2         3       (Gross - Total - Insurance e.g: 1-2-3)
```

And this calculation has to be done for each line of the report.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
SUM({Table1.GrossAmt}, {Table1.ID})-SUM({Table1.Total}, {Table1.ID})-SUM({Table1.Insurance}, {Table1.ID})
```

And this gives me the error: `currency or number is expecting {Table1.GrossAmt}`

But I am confused how to achieve this. Please help me.  Thank you

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is what I have done so far: SUM({Table1.GrossAmt}, {Table1.ID})-SUM({Table1.Total}, {Table1.ID})-SUM({Table1.Insurance}, {Table1.ID}) And this gives me the error: "currency or number is expecting {Table1.GrossAmt}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to cast the `Currency` field to a `Numeric`:

```
ToNumber(SUM({Table1.GrossAmt}, {Table1.ID})) - SUM({Table1.Total}, {Table1.ID}) - SUM({Table1.Insurance}, {Table1.ID})
```